# Mount an ext3 partition in Windows, inside a Dynamic Disk?

Tags: windows, drivers, ext3, dynamic-disk

I have a disk which has two partitions, one NTFS and one ext3. I've converted it to a dynamic disk inside Windows. It still can be read fine when booted under Linux (thanks to LDM support in the Linux kernel), however when booted under Windows, the ext2/ext3 driver [ext2ifs](http://fs-driver.org/) no longer works. It cannot see the partitions inside the dynamic disk.

Is there a way to make ext2ifs work? If not, are there any other ext2/ext3 drivers compatible with Windows that I can try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ext2ifs doesn't support inodes larger than 128.

Though I've never tried it, [ext2fsd](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ext2fsd/) looks stable enough as far as people say.

Comment: It almost works...ext2fsd sees the drive, sees the EXT3 label, but it cannot mount it.

Comment: So somehow it started working all of the sudden. I opened My Computer, noticed a new drive letter, and there it was, mounting my partition. I swear for sure it had not worked previously, even after rebooting multiple times. Dunno what's different now.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Windows 7, you can use [Ext2Explore](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ext2read/files/Ext2read%20Version%202.2%20%28Latest%29/ext2explore-2.2.71.zip/download?use_mirror=nchc).

It doesn't mount ext3 partitions but allows you to explore them. You can see and save files from your Linux partitions.