# accessing linux directories from windows

Tags: windows-7, windows, linux, fedora, mount

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I get access to EXT2, EX3 and EXT4 partitions on Windows 7?](https://superuser.com/questions/373806/how-can-i-get-access-to-ext2-ex3-and-ext4-partitions-on-windows-7)

I want to access linux drives from windows. I have ubuntu and fedora installed along with windows. I can easily access/mount drives created by windows from linux but is there any way i can access/mount the directories/drive i have in fedora and ubuntu from windows ?

Comment: -1, Question does not show research effort. [How can I get access to EXT2, EX3 and EXT4 partitions on Windows 7?](http://superuser.com/questions/373806/how-can-i-get-access-to-ext2-ex3-and-ext4-partitions-on-windows-7), [Mount an ext3 partition in Windows, inside a Dynamic Disk?](http://superuser.com/questions/51348/mount-an-ext3-partition-in-windows-inside-a-dynamic-disk), [Mount ext3fs in Windows](http://superuser.com/questions/8298/mount-ext3fs-in-windows)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows doesn't have native support for the ext3/4 filesystems that most Linux distributions use. Third-party solutions exist, however. Start by checking out [Ext2Fsd](http://www.ext2fsd.com/), which seems to be the most popular option. There's also [Ext2Read](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ext2read/), but it's read-only and works as a standalone application, unlike Ext2Fsd which installs as a filesystem driver and allows writing as well.

Another alternative would be to format your data partition with a filesystem that both Linux and Windows can read and write reliable, for example FAT32. Modern Linux distributions should have pretty decent support for NTFS as well.

Answer (score -1):

You will need external file system drivers to do that. There are some applications out there who can help you with that. Ext2Fsd seems to be one of them, look for it here http://www.webupd8.org/2011/08/access-ext4-ext3-or-ext2-partitions-in.html
Alternatively, try to look for it on Google.